# Full names and abbreviations of the `leqno` and `fleqn` options in amsmath

Tags: amsmath

In the [user's guide for the `amsmath` package (Version 2.1)](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) on page 3, the descriptions for the options `leqno` and `fleqn` are as follows:

> `leqno`: Place equation numbers on the left.

> `fleqn`: Position equations at a fixed indent from the left margin rather than centered in the text column.

However, the meaning of the abbreviations "leqno" and "fleqn" are not immediately clear from these descriptions. In a response on this [link](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9645), the following meanings were suggested:

> `leqno`: left equation numbers

> `fleqn`: flush left equations

According to [Merriam-Webster Dictionary's entry for "no,"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no#:%7E:text=%5BLatin%20numero%2C%20ablative%20of%20numerus%5D%20number) which states that it is derived from the Latin word "numero" (ablative of "numerus"), it can be understood as meaning "number."

Therefore, it can be inferred that `leqno` stands for "**l**eft **eq**uation **no**". However, it is unclear what the "n" in `fleqn` stands for if it is interpreted as "**f**lush **l**eft **eq**uations."

I was not able to find a definitive explanation for the abbreviations `leqno` and `fleqn` and their corresponding words through a search engine. It seems that the suggested meanings are based on reasonable deductions/guesses.

PS: English is not my native language, so please forgive any typos or inaccuracies in my expression. If there is any unclear part of my question, please let me know, and I will be happy to rephrase it until we can communicate effectively. Similarly, I am willing to do what I can to help in the process of finding an answer.

Comment: I am going to guess that `fleqn` does stand for `flush left equations` i.e. "**f**lush **l**eft **eq**uatio**n**s". In English, the letters for an abbreviation do not need to immediately follow each other so I think this is the same too. `eqn` is typically used as the abbreviation for `equation` in my previous experience but I do not know the internals of `amsmath` so cannot be authoritive

Comment: @JamesT Thank you, even if your answer may not be authoritative, your experience still resolved most of my confusion on this question. Perhaps only the author of `amsmath` can give an authoritative explanation. Personally, I even feel that this question has already been resolved.

Comment: Note that `fleqn` exists also in the kernel and `amsmath` just redefines it, so the question is probably unrelated to `amsmath`.

Comment: Actually, the "fl" in `\fleqn` does not mean "flush to the left margin", at least in `amsmath`.  The "fixed indent" is meaningful, and it has the width `\mathindent` (default 30pt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\base\leqno.clo`:

> left equation numbers

As shown in `C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\tex\latex\base\fleqn.clo`:

> flush left equations

Comment: `\fleqn` in `amsmath` means "flush left to a fixed indent", `\mathindent` (default = 30pt).

Comment: @Clara Thank you for your answer! I have marked your answer as the correct one, but as my reputation is less than 15, I am unable to upvote your answer.